# Rear/Front Mic not shown on Sound manager

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, microphone, volume-control

With Ubuntu 11.10, in the Sound options, in the Input tab were my 2 microphones, an usb one and the headset, connected to the Rear/Front Microphone. Now, 12.04, it only shows the Usb microphone.
The headset microphone also works, but I have to configure it from Pulse Audio volume control. I need both, so I want to configure them easily from the sound options.
Why this mic is not shown? I have seen I'm not the only one with this problem,  but I haven't found any solution.
Thanks for reading and your help

Comment: what soundcard, which mic?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with unity desktop, if you use gnome shell it will show you the hardware options on sound manager and then select duplexStereo or duplex+whateverSurround

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Install pavucontrol and select the right in input devices.